linear gradient with percentages - does not work
front look
css look
this is the div's attributes ------> height: 250px, width: 600px;
I tried to define a linear gradient using percentages but I ran into some problems.
The percentages do not work as I expected in any example.
Let's say in a second example each cycle is 45% but on the screen you can see that the cycle repeats about 6 times, meaning the total is not 100%.
Maybe the 100% is not the div's?
Maybe 100% of something else?
I would really appreciate your help, I'm stuck on this for a long time.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. IMAGES OF CODE ARE NOT AN ACCEPTABLE REPLACEMENT.

My suggestion is to use a CSS gradient generator, and then you can look at the code while playing around to understand linear-gradients better: https://cssgradient.io/

Percentages in linear-gradient and repeating-linear-gradient does not sum, they are stop positions.
When you write this:
#gradient9 {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(red 5%, orange 10%, yellow 20%, green 10%);
}

You get exactly what you see:

Position 0 no color, so inherit red from the following.
Position 5% red
5% to 10% gradient red to orange
Position 10% orange
10% to 20% gradient orange to yellow
Position 20% yellow
20% back to 10% gradient from yellow to green, but we cannot see that because is covered from previous colors
Position 100% nothing, inherit green from the last one.

If you want a color in position 100% you need to write 100%, because your values do not sum.
Here is the CSS rule you are looking for:
#gradient9 {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(red 5%, orange 15%, yellow 35%, green 45%);
}

In this case you'll have:

Position 0 no color, so inherit red from the following.
Position 5% red
5% to 15% gradient red to orange
Position 15% orange
15% to 35% gradient orange to yellow
Position 35% yellow
35% to 45 gradient from yellow to green
Then again from red



.gradient {
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.g1 {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(red 5%, orange 10%, yellow 20%, green 10%);
}
.g2 {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(red 5%, orange 15%, yellow 35%, green 45%);
}
<div class="gradient g1"></div>
<div class="gradient g2"></div>




when the green show up? And how does the green know how much to catch? and 100% from what ? and px works diffrent right? Pixels we sum?
Regarding the last code

@maayan I think you may be confused between 'ordinary' linear-gradient and repeating-linear-gradient. The latter repeats the color stops. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/repeating-linear-gradient
